# Linq Contains The type arguments cannot be inferred

Tags: linq, contains

```
 string[] companyIdsUnfiltered = companyIdsCsv.Split(',');
```

[image]

Up above my code and my error.

[Link to bigger picture](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2lncs5i.jpg)

The code is as follows:

```
string[] companyIdsUnfiltered = companyIdsCsv.Split(',');
var query = (from c in ctx.Companies
             join co in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals co.Id
             where companyIdsUnfilteres.Contains(c.Id)
             select c.Id).ToArray();
```

Comment: what is `companyIdsCsv`? (I can't see the screenshot since the destination is blocked for me).

Comment: Please edit the *text* of your code into the question, rather than an image which ends up looking tiny. Then copy the *text* of the error message in. There's no need for an image here.

Comment: bigger picture link is broken

Comment: What is the type of `c.Id`?

Comment: How hard is to host an image compared to a CTRL+C...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the error I guess the solution is to cast `c.Id` to string.

```
var query = (from c in ctx.Companies
             join co in ctx.Countries on c.CountryId equals co.Id
             where companyIdsUnfilteres.Contains((string) c.Id)
             select c.Id).ToArray();
```

Just to add, if casting to `string` is not possible, try `c.Id.ToString()` as well. And take care of nulls etc..